# google maps V3 infoboxes - expand map borders?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, bing-maps

I am developing a [wordpress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery-geo/) which displays some photos on a map. Detailed Information are displayed in an infobox / infowindow.

This works fine for bing maps 6.3, the infoboxes exeeds the border of the maps.

Example: http://www.denktfrei.de/?p=805

Now I wan't to add support for Google maps 3 and Bing Maps 7. Both APIs does not support such infoboxes, the infobox/infowindow can't be larger than the map. 
How can I manage to create such infoboxes anyway?

Comment: What you can easily do is to manage your own infobox out of the map control and set its position based on the relative position on the page. In this way, you infobox won't be 'clipped' to the control. It can work on both APIs.

Comment: Yes, that should work. I use the markers DOM and opentip- works fine! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the comment, I would recommend to use a custom infobox added to the DOM out of the map control itself. In this way you won't be limited to the DIV container of the map control.

See the code below for an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map = null;

        function getMap() {

            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('myMap'), 
                { 
                    credentials: 'YOURKEY', 
                    showCopyright: false
                });

            // Create the pushpin
            var pushpin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.5, 2.75));

            // Add the pushpin to the map
            map.entities.push(pushpin);

            // Bind the click event on the pushpin
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pushpin, 'click', function(e) {
                if (e.targetType == 'pushpin') {
                    var box = document.getElementById('infobox');
                    box.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
                    box.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
                    box.style.visibility = 'visible';
                }
            });
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getMap();">
    <div id="container" style="position:relative;"></div>
    <div id="myMap" style="position: absolute;z-index:1; width: 800px; height: 600px;">
    </div>
    <div id="infobox" style="float:left;z-index:2; visibility:hidden;position:absolute; width:500px; height: 300px; background-color:White; border: 1px solid #333;">Sample content for an infobox which should be larger than the map control.</div>
</body>
</html>
```